# Why is my Swift code function only running once?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ibaction, iboutlet

So I'm new to programming and I'm working on a Swift tax calculator learning exercise. At the moment, I'm just trying to set up a few things before I start plugging the calculations in.

I'm trying to get the code to take a text input, interpolate it into a string and print that in a text view.

So far, my code works once, but from then on it seems to stop working. I essentially just want my code to reset itself when the user clicks inside the first input text field.

I've tried setting the text view to "", but that doesn't seem to work. It just interpolates "", which is not what I want.

Here's my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var income: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var takeHomePay: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        income.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    @IBAction func calculateTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if takeHomePay.text.isEmpty {
        takeHomePay.text = "You are earning $\(income.text!)"
        } else if !takeHomePay.text.isEmpty {
            takeHomePay.text = "You need to enter a figure"
        } else {
            takeHomePay.text = "ERROR"
        }

    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        income.resignFirstResponder()
    }

}

extension ViewController : UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

}
```

Why is my function only running once? I want to see the output change every time I change the input. Probably a simple fix, but as I say, I am only learning.

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you talking about "calculateTapped" function here you want that run on every singe entry of your textfield isn't ?

Answer (score 1):

Add the delegate to the textView inside `viewDidLoad`

```
takeHomePay.delegate = self
```

Then implement

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if takeHomePay.text.isEmpty {
        takeHomePay.text = "You are earning $\(income.text!)"
        } else {
            takeHomePay.text = "You need to enter a figure"
        } 
}
```

The bottom most else can't be reached as the textView is either empty or not

---

```
class VCName:UIViewController,UITextViewDelegate{}
```

Comment: This throws an error "Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type 'UITextViewDelegate'. What am I missing?